# How to create ethereum withdrawal system on a site?

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I want to create an ethereum withdrawal system on my site. I know how to send transactions with web3and do other things but I have one problem. If you are trying to send transaction while you already have a processing transaction you will get an error:

> {'code': -32000, 'message': 'known transaction: (txn hash)'}

That means that I can't just process transactions without stopping. So how can I do it? Should I make a queue or something like that? I heard I can do it with promises but I don't know how.

Comment: There is an example on how to use promises with web3 on the documentation. Try to follow this example: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction . When the function in `.then()` executes it means that the transaction has completed. Also instead of `.then()` you may want to look at `await` since it is a little easier to understand.

Comment: FYI https://medium.com/@jgm.orinoco/releasing-stuck-ethereum-transactions-1390149f297d